# UIPinchGestureRecognizer not getting called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am not really sure why the target is not getting called when I do this:

```
 UIImage * imgSrc = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageSource]]];
            UIImageView * imgView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imgSrc] retain];

            UIPinchGestureRecognizer * pinchGestureRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(resizeImage:)];
            [imgView addGestureRecognizer:pinchGestureRecognizer]; 
            [pinchGestureRecognizer release];

- (IBAction)resizeImage:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
   //not getting here
}
```

the resize image is not getting called. The image is shown just fine

Comment: In what method is the gesture recognizer initialized and added to the image view? When is `imgView` added to the view hierarchy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the imgView.userInteractionEnabled = YES. It is default to "NO".